# Google Event Creating without hangout meeting

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api, google-meet

I have a requirement that i need to create an Event with a videocall, the problem is that after the Event is created for some reason is not creating a HangoutLink.

Here is my code:

```
var myEvent = new Event()
                {
                    Summary = "Google Meet 1",
                    Start = new EventDateTime()
                    {
                        DateTime = new DateTime(2023, 7, 19, 17, 0, 0), 
                        TimeZone = "America/Mexico_City" 
                    },
                    End = new EventDateTime()
                    {
                        DateTime = new DateTime(2023, 7, 19, 18, 0, 0), 
                        TimeZone = "America/Mexico_City" 
                    },
                    ConferenceData = new ConferenceData()
                    {
                       
                        CreateRequest = new CreateConferenceRequest()
                        {
                            RequestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                            ConferenceSolutionKey = new ConferenceSolutionKey()
                            {
                                Type = "hangoutsMeet"
                            }
                           
                    }

                    },
                Attendees = new List<EventAttendee>()
                {
                    new EventAttendee() { Email = "test@gmail.com" }
                }
            };
```

Is there something that i am missing?

Comment: Google Hangouts was retired; don't use this tag. With the [google-calendar-api] you should be OK. By the way, you should add a [mcve].